# Having a hard time retrieving the customer_id getId() from createCustomer object to pass to createCustomerCard

Tags: php, square-connect

Here is my code which is the example I used from [here](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-createcustomer)

```
$createcustomer_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\CustomersApi();
$createcustomer_result = $createcustomer_api->createCustomer(array(
  'given_name' => 'Amelia',
  'family_name' => 'Earhart',
  'email_address' => 'Amelia.Earhart@example.com',
  'address' => array(
    'address_line_1' => '500 Electric Ave',
    'address_line_2' => 'Suite 600',
    'locality' => 'New York',
    'administrative_district_level_1' => 'NY',
    'postal_code' => '10003',
    'country' => 'US'
  ),
  'phone_number' => '1-555-555-0122',
  'reference_id' => 'YOUR_REFERENCE_ID',
  'note' => 'a customer'
));
```

If I print out the results I get

```
SquareConnect\Model\CreateCustomerResponse Object
(
    [errors:protected] => 
    [customer:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Customer Object
        (
            [id:protected] => CBASEHtp6YVU8AirkMv1lrVMyoIgAQ
            [created_at:protected] => 2017-09-27T23:19:44.62Z
            [updated_at:protected] => 2017-09-27T23:19:44.62Z
            [cards:protected] => 
            [given_name:protected] => Amelia
            [family_name:protected] => Earhart
            [nickname:protected] => 
            [company_name:protected] => 
            [email_address:protected] => Amelia.Earhart@example.com
            [address:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Address Object
                (
                    [address_line_1:protected] => 500 Electric Ave
                    [address_line_2:protected] => Suite 600
                    [address_line_3:protected] => 
                    [locality:protected] => New York
                    [sublocality:protected] => 
                    [sublocality_2:protected] => 
                    [sublocality_3:protected] => 
                    [administrative_district_level_1:protected] => NY
                    [administrative_district_level_2:protected] => 
                    [administrative_district_level_3:protected] => 
                    [postal_code:protected] => 10003
                    [country:protected] => US
                    [first_name:protected] => 
                    [last_name:protected] => 
                    [organization:protected] => 
                )

            [phone_number:protected] => 1-555-555-0122
            [reference_id:protected] => YOUR_REFERENCE_ID
            [note:protected] => a customer
            [preferences:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\CustomerPreferences Object
                (
                    [email_unsubscribed:protected] => 
                )

            [groups:protected] => 
        )

)
```

Now I need to create the customer card to associate with the customer for future recurring payments.

```
$createcard_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\CustomersApi();
$createcard_result = $createcard_api->createCustomerCard($createcustomer_result->getId(), array(
  'card_nonce' => $nonce,
  'billing_address' => array(
    'address_line_1' => '1455 Market St',
    'address_line_2' => 'Suite 600',
    'locality' => 'San Francisco',
    'administrative_district_level_1' => 'CA',
    'postal_code' => '94103',
    'country' => 'US'
  ),
  'cardholder_name' => 'Amelia Earhart'
));
```

From what I understand there is a built-in function with the square SDK that is `getId()` which according to [this](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-createcustomercard) is called like `$customer->getId()`, but according to [this](https://github.com/mage2pro/square-php-sdk) I need to just add `->getId()` to my `createCustomer` object.

So I am trying to call the `getId()` function as

```
$createcustomer_result->getId()
```

but in my code I am getting the error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method SquareConnect\Model\CreateCustomerResponse::getId()
```

How do I properly get the customer id from the `createCustomer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've only got the response object from the API, a communication device.  You need to first extract the created object from the response, then you can query it for the ID.

```
$customer = $createcustomer_result->getCustomer();
```

That should get you the actual customer object, then you can:

```
$customer_id = $customer->getId();
```

This is pretty common for API libraries.  You can also query the response object for errors if they occur.  When using these kinds of libraries, have a look inside the various classes and read through the functions, you can get a better idea of how you use them that way.

Comment: you would happen to know how to get the Customercard ID? I tried using `$createcard_result->getCustomerCard();` but that didnt work.

Comment: and where did you find the `getCustomer()` documentation? I cant find that anywhere.